# C beginner about file

Tags: c, file

EDIT: I wanted to input a string, not a char.
For example, I write num = 3, string = "hello" and month = 10

I want the output in the file to be 3hello10 .

I was trying to write two values and store it in a file. However, when I tried reading it, I received weird outputs. I am not sure which part that I am doing wrong.

**I was actually wanting to concatenate every variable in one line in a file. Therefore, I used fscanf("%format", var1, ..);**

this is my write.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int num, month;
    char ch;

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("myfile.txt","w");
    if(fptr == NULL) {
            printf("Error!");   
            exit(1);             
    }

    printf("Enter ID: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%s",&ch);

    printf("Enter birth of month: ");
    scanf("%d", &month);

    fprintf(fptr,"%c%d%d", ch, num, month);
    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}
```

this is my read.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char c[1000];
    FILE *fptr;

    if ((fptr = fopen("myfile.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        exit(1);         
    }

    // reads text until newline 
    fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]", c);
    printf("Data from the file:\n%s", c);
    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}

When executing the write.c program

Enter ID: 111
Enter string: hello
Enter birth of month: 6
```

When executing the read.c program

```
Data from the file:
Data from the file:
h18693766136
```

I am a complete beginner of C. So, any clarification in regard to my logic or code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the output file first with a hex editor  (for instance od -x -c) and inspect if the output is what you expected it to be

Comment: IOW: `char ch;` -> `char ch[100];` and `scanf("%s",&ch);` -> `scanf("%s", ch);` and `fprintf(fptr,"%c%d%d", ch, num, month);`  -> `fprintf(fptr,"%s%d%d", ch, num, month);`. Or simply `scanf("%s",&ch);` -> `scanf("%c", &ch);`. It's unclear if you want to read a single char or a string. You should [edit]  your question and show an example of input and expected output.

Comment: @Jabberwocky  i just modified following your instructions (which is correct for my write.c) . But I read the output, the output is only m.

Comment: What did you modify? I suggested two different things.

Comment: I wanted a string my var string. So I modified some of variables and printf.

Comment: These kind of bugs are common when someone is moving from a higher level language to C. You need to study strings and arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is with your write implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
int num, month;
char ch[100];  //declare a char array as you are readinh a string

FILE *fptr;
fptr = fopen("myfile.txt","w");
if(fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error!");   
        exit(1);             
}

printf("Enter ID: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

printf("Enter string: ");
scanf("%s",ch); //read as a string

printf("Enter birth of month: ");
scanf("%d", &month);

fprintf(fptr,"%s\t%d\t%d\t", ch, num, month); //writing into file with some formatting 
fclose(fptr);

return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To store a string, you need a char array, not a char type. So I changed char to char array. Also, char arrays point to address values ​​by the variable name itself. So you should not add & when using scanf. And you want to be input in order of num-string-month. So I changed the order of the variables in fprintf.

This is write.c

```
int num, month;
char ch[100];       //char -> char[]

FILE *fptr;
fptr = fopen("myfile.txt","w");
if(fptr == NULL) {
    printf("Error!");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Enter ID: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

printf("Enter string: ");
scanf("%s", ch);            //&ch -> ch

printf("Enter birth of month: ");
scanf("%d", &month);

fprintf(fptr,"%d%s%d", num, ch, month);     // %c -> %s and change variable order change
fclose(fptr);
```

I modified printf for clean output.
This is read.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
char c[1000];
FILE *fptr;

if ((fptr = fopen("myfile.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error! opening file");
    exit(1);
}

// reads text until newline
fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]", c);
printf("Data from the file:%s\n", c);       //\n%s -> %s\n
fclose(fptr);

return 0;
}
```